# navigation menu tabs pure css

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a good css technique to use nav tabs that look exactly like this:

[image]

I have a div with a logo that has a background and I want the tabs to overlap exactly like in the pic.

I don't want to use drupal's entire html and css structure as I need it to be lightweight. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: please show your code what you did till now & where you stuck

Comment: @sandeep: I have no idea how to get the tabs to be right in the logo div like the pic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll point you to this website: http://pea.rs/  for some good CSS design patterns.

And more spefically this page: http://pea.rs//navigation/horizontal-tabs

There's a pretty good modern browser version of what you're looking for, sans filling in your background and logo.

Of course, border-radius isn't supported in IE8 and below, so you'll either have to be ok with that or use one of the many round-corner techniques.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The main thing is that I need it to overlap the logo div

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by overlapping.  The menu is simply inside a header div that also contains a logo block.  Something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/8p2Wx/2/

Comment: Perfect, btw what does `.cf:before,.cf:after { content:""; display:table; }`
and
`.cf:after { clear:both; }`
 do?

Comment: Also, isn't `<nav>` not really that supported? I saw you're trying to include older versions of IE, wouldn't that break in IE?

Comment: @qwertymk the 'cf' class is for clearfix.  Clearfix is a pretty basic CSS tool used to help clear containers with floated elements.  This new clearfix code is calls "clearfix micro" and comes from here: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/  One of the original articles I read about clearfix is here: http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html I think that does a decent job explaining it.

Comment: Regarding IE. I wasn't trying to target any IE, that was copy/paste from the clearfix code. The fiddle is only a simple example mashup based on the http://pea.rs/ website and your drupal image.  It's not exactly trying to cover all the bases. NAV is an HTML5 element which isn't supported in IE8 and less as shown here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic  However, there's a JavaScript fix for that known as HTML5 shiv http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Shiv  You can also simply replace NAV with DIV to avoid HTML5 compatibility issues.